# Is it possible to test SQL AlwaysOn Availability Groups on a single developer workstation?

Tags: sql-server

I have implemented executing sqlcmd.exe to run a script (provided by hosting & ops DBAs) that copies a newly created database in the C# app that creates the database to a second server in an AlwaysOn Availability Group. Unfortunately we have no AlwaysOn Availability support in our development or integration environments so I have only been able to test executing sqlcmd to run the script and handling the script failure. Is it at all possible for me to simulate the AlwaysOn Availability Group environment on my developer workstation if a create a second SQL Server instance. I am running SQL 2014 Developer Edition at the moment but should it be required, will be able to upgrade to SQL 2016 Developer Edition.

If this is not possible we will be forced to deploy without full end to end testing and have the first end to end tests happen in the production environment.

I have fairly good developer level SQL skills; in other words I'm very comfortable with stored procedures and such but have very little knowledge of the new and advanced features for actually administering SQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you will either have to create VM  (Virtual Machines) using VMWare software or VMs using Microsoft (MS) technology. There are other VM products but these two are used for the majority of virtualizations of the SQL Server/Microsoft stack. If you use MS technology you can download the software for usually up to 90 days (free) without activating the software. I would do it on an SSD so it finishes in a timely basis and you probably need 12-16GB of memory on the host, developer, machine.

There are detailed online instructions on creating VMs for SQL Server on clusters. The best ones have screen shots.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. With little space free on my SSD and only 8GB of memory, it should prove to be a fun exercise.

Comment: I was going to suggest putting the Domain Controller on one of the SQL Server boxes but if you are testing fail over that won't work. But I would not worry for a Proof of Concept of coalescing machines.